# How do I get the effect of a text bubble on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have the effect of a text bubble over my social media icons on hover.  If you want an example I would like it to look similar to this page http://easysite.by/?theme=teardrop

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) That being said, google for `css tooltip` or something similar.

Comment: I had no idea what to do that is why I asked on here.  I didn't know a -3 feedback would take effect for asking a question.  I had googled to text bubble on hover and things of that nature but I did not know the term to google was css tooltip.  Thanks though.

Comment: That is understandable. It just makes your question look better if you, in the original post, include what you've already tried to solve your problem. It shows you're not just coming here first thing and have put some thought into it. A lot of the time, you'll find the solution you're looking for as you're writing a good question.

Comment: You may want to look at a jquery implementation using qtip. See docs and demo here http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Comment: @sachleen I understand that I should have written a little more and told the research I had done previously.  That being said even after researching the tooltips I can't find the solution to my problem.  I can't find a way to do this with images that already have classes and the same goes for ease in-out webkits for images.  I am tryin to figure out how to do both.

Comment: @dexter thank you for that site but I don't see the answer using those methods either.  they all are using text based or div/a that don't have classes assigned already

Comment: What do you mean? I thought you wanted text bubble when hovered? and qtip can handle that with ease. All you need is to bind your anchors to qtip, and it does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle implemented qtip on social buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/YYwmw/